# ActiveMQ-CPP package for Ubuntu

Tags: package-management

I need Apache ActiveMQ-CPP library package for ubuntu. I know there is build for Fedora, but I can't find one for Ubuntu.

Do you know where I can download the package?

I've already build one with checkinstall but I'm not quite sure how portable it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can download it from [here](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/emisoft.web.cern.ch/emisoft/dists/EMI/2/debian/pool/third-party/a/activemq-cpp/)

**Or**

You can use the rpm package and change to deb via **ALIEN**

to install alien command on Ubuntu

```
 sudo apt-get install alien
```

To use alien command to convert rpm to deb file

```
 sudo alien pakage.rpm
```

Output would be:
   package.deb generated

you can use

```
sudo alien -i package.rpm
```

this would convert the package from rpm to deb then install it automatically and then it would delete the source.

```
man alien
```

will show you how to use

**Moreover**
 see this link that talk [how to build](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/building.html) the ActiveMQ package

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Package provided by feodora contains only the library without header files. Do you know how can include them ?

Comment: You can download the debian. See the updated answer